# Caching header with mongodb timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, caching

Found this issue when testing caching using mongodb as our data storage. The last-modified date is being correctly, but it by its specification it doesn't include milliseconds thus when the node JS controller tries to compare them they are different:

```
Fri Feb 27 2015 09:15:00 GMT+0000 (GMT) - Mongo DB date
Fri Feb 27 2015 09:15:00 GMT+0000 (GMT) - if-modified-since
```

Controller values:

```
1425028500987 - Mongo DB date
1425028500000 - if-modified-since
```

As you can see the mongodb includes milliseconds. Has anybody a nice way to clean up the date to reset milliseconds?

Thanks.

J

Comment: Do you have control over the mongoDB time value before you do the compare, if so, then reset the 3 digits to zero then compare.

Comment: Have control, looking for a nice way to handle this scenario so that the time is dealt with i.e. replacing the last digits with 000.

Comment: try (long)(((double)time/1000) * 1000)

Comment: Think this is cleaner  var lastModDate = new Date(updated_at);
                    lastModDate.setMilliseconds('000');
                    if (reqModDate.getTime() >= lastModDate.getTime()) {...}

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job:

```
 var reqModDate = new Date(req.header(IF_MODIFIED_SINCE));
 var lastModDate = new Date(updated_at);
 lastModDate.setMilliseconds('000');

// if-modified-since header is only good to the second while mongo is to the millisecond
if (reqModDate.getTime() >= lastModDate.getTime()) {
```